# Security Center service does not start with error code 1068

Tags: windows-vista, services, security-center

I'm on Windows Vista (SP1), and for some reason whenever I try to start the `Security Center` Windows service it returns the error code 1068, stating that dependent services are not running.

What does Security Center depend on, and how can I start those services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the following services need to be both `Enabled` and set to `Automatic` (or `Automatic (Delayed Start)`):

1. Remote Procedure Call (`RPC`)
2. Windows Management Instrumentation (`WMI`)

For me, enabling WMI fixed the problem.